# Office Addin problem

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, add-in

I'm currently developing an add-in aimed to edit office documents stored in a codendi forge. 
First problem was the read only flag on my file. A simple ‘save as’ solved that problem. 
This solution was ok until I removed codendi’s cookie then instead of my file I received an error page.

What I want to do is to be able to catch an event triggered by office before it starts downloading the file. Then I can prompt the user for authentication and recreate a cookie by myself without the need for the user to open internet explorer and sign in.

Is there a way to catch an event indicating that word, excel and powerpoint are about to start a download?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really understand what you want to do. 
I don't think any office application actually downloads the wanted file, it is downloaded by your browser in a temporary file and therefrom opened by it. 
I think that if you want to edit the file from you client, the best way would be to use the soap interface, which is part of Codendi. Have a look to

[yourforgehostname]/soap

[yourforgehostname]/soap/codendi.wsdl.php?wsdl

If you want to see the wsdl in a more readable form consider using

http://tomi.vanek.sk/index.php?page=wsdl-viewer

One of the supported API is login

Hope it helps

Comment: Ok now that I read my question I recon that I was a bit unclear. My problem was with the redirection with internet explorer. For all other browsers I'll need to create an add-on to open files directly with the appropriate office tool.

Comment: The aim of this add-in was to edit files without the need to make a save as and upload the file. My problem wasn't with codendi but with office. Thanks for your help.